# Why some folders have the .DS_Store but some doesn't? 

Tags: finder, macos

## Local storage

In some of my folder, I found something quite interesting:

```
Some folders have the `.DS_Store` but some does not
```

## Network storage

`.DS_Store` files are not on the network store. Any reason?

Thanks.

Comment: The second question, about network storage, will be easier to answer if the file system type is known. In Terminal run a one-word command, `mount` to reveal the type.

Answer (score 1):

## Locally stored .DS_Store files

### In brief

A common reason for presence of `.DS_Store`:

- in Finder, a view is preferred.

### Technical details

An answer to [Why are dot underscore ._ files created, and how can I avoid them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14980/8546):

- [Purposes of .DS_Store and ._ files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51147/8546)

Comment: I have tried to change using the 4 views, but no .DS_Store was created.