# See all Apple Hidden Files

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

I came from Windows 2 years ago and I knew there were hidden files in all OS's. As Windows has the simple option to show them to you, I supposed that if I contacted Apple support they would tell me how to show hidden files. But they simply told me they didn't exist at Mac OS. So I had to find the answer myself.

But today I was browsing some files with the terminal, I did `ls -l -a` to see all files (including those hidden) in a list and I saw kind of a different file that began with a dot and an underscore (`._`). I could see in the Finder all files except that one.

So my question is: **Why can't I see that file (e.g. `._hello`) in the Finder if I have already configured it to show me all files, including the hidden ones?** Is that another kind of hidden file which I'm not aware of?

Comment: see this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

Comment: @MateuszSzloesk thank you, that was useful but I don't understand yet why doesn't finder show them. I just wanna know that, I don't actually wanna see them :)

Comment: It's not visible in Finder, because informations are stored as extended attributes (Finder "merges" them into original file). You can see them with `ls -la@` or using `xattr` command.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 kinds of hidden files on `OS X`.

Files starting with `.` are normally hidden in Unix (including OS X) or Linux systems, but can easily be shown e.g. by `ls -la`.

In addition certain files (or directories) are hidden by OS X apps ( `~/Library` is one example) and generally files inside `bundles` (such as .apps) are not normally visible.

It is easy to show hidden files in Finder (by changing settings `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`). This then applies to all files.

Finder addons such as `TotalFinder` make changing this easier and Finder alternatives such as QuollEyeTree http://binnie.id.au/QuollEyeTree.html let you toggle this for individual directories and show both kinds of hidden files.

Comment: OP was not asking how He can see hidden files but why He can't see `._*` files in Finder. "*I have already configured it to show me all files, including the hidden ones*"