# How to show dot underscore ._ files?

Tags: macos, file

I want the OSX to show all kind of hidden files including `._` files too. I do not know exactly what I did, but I am successful in seeing `.DS_STORE` files, but not `._` files. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: You know you're unlikely to see dot underscore files on the Mac itself. It only writes them to drives that can't store the Mac's extended attributes correctly - NTFS drives etc

Comment: How are the drives that ._ should be on formatted? And how were the ._ files created

Comment: @Mark In my particular case the files were created on a windows machine and have been zipped and sent to me on mail. On unzipping, they show me an empty folder.

Answer (score 2):

Open up terminal, and write:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

This makes you see dot files and hidden files in a grayish tint. You open . files with right click open. I do not know why you cannot just double click them though. If it is a problem, ask a separate question on that.

---

Just a little bonus:
You can hide files by issuing:

```
chflags hidden /path/to/file
```

and unhide by issuing:

```
chflags nohidden /path/to/file
```

Comment: OP has already done this as he sees .DS_Store issue is ._ which requires more info

Comment: Mark is right. This is exactly what I did and I tried again. I can see dot files, but not dot underscore files.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that zip files just contain one string per path whilst OS X paths point to a file and also metadata and resource forks. When HFS+ directories are zipped OS X tools will put this metadata and other info into ._ files in the zip if copying to another file system. See this [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them) question

I think (but have not found a reference) that when an OS X aware tool unzips an archive with ._ files in it will reapply them as metadata or resource forks i.e. the opposite action to the one that created the ._ files

Comment: That's right, `._*` are usually Extended Attributes and are "merged" into original file on OS X file system.