# Hidden files on Windows machine generated by OS X

Tags: windows, macos

When I transfer a folder FROM my Mac To a Windows machine by a flash memory, on the Windows system there are hidden files with the same names as the original files inside the folder. If I choose that Windows not to show the hidden files then they become invisible. When the folder contains a huge number of files then the scene is awkward and confusing and sometimes people think that there are malwares on my flash memory.

**How can I get rid of these hidden files when I transfer folders from Mac to Windows?**

Comment: @Monomeeth @Community That other question talks about Spotlight/Trash files. @amin-r seems to be talking about resource forks. Which aren't covered by that question. You know the files which look like `._ExampleFile.psd` that sit beside regular files?

Comment: This question is more relevant. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

Comment: @Alistair Community♦ is a bot, no need to @ mention them (also you cannot @ mention two users in a single comment). The bot being used to mark a question as duplicate indicates that OP themselves agreed with the proposed duplicate and marked their own question as duplicate. Just for your information