# With WebDAV provided by Microsoft SharePoint, how can users of OS X minimise risks of corruption and multiuser overwrites?

Tags: macos, ms-office, webdav, microsoft-sharepoint

There are various OS X approaches to using the **WebDAV service provided by Microsoft SharePoint**.

## Integrity of data

Answers to this question focus on integrity:

- when a file is used by a single user
- when a file is used by multiple users.

Whilst some parts of an answer may be generalised to WebDAV servers in general, this question focuses on SharePoint – where **Microsoft's server and client restrictions** cause people to seek **alternatives to Microsoft Document Connection**.

Some overlap with an earlier question:

- [Is it possible to mount SharePoint as a volume in 10.6?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7030/8546)

### Reference

Drafted in May 2012 a table:

- [File open/lock protection for multi-user use of Microsoft SharePoint](http://content.wuala.com/contents/grahamperrin/Documents/2012/05/14/a/locking-sharepoint-table.html)

Key points from that draft:

- restrictions in SharePoint make Microsoft Office 2011 incompatible with file system integration
- [Microsoft Document Connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/56192/8546) lacks file system integration.

If any reader can draw a conclusion that differs from what's tabled: I'll welcome discussion in Ask Different Chat, or add your answer below.

Some parts of that table will become answers to this question …

Answer (score 1):

## Use the web interface provided by SharePoint

Tested with the following apps:

- LibreOffice
- Microsoft Excel
- Microsoft PowerPoint
- Microsoft Word
- NeoOffice.

### Pros

For multiple users of SharePoint, protection through the web interface seems good.

### Cons

No file system integration.

Answer (score 0):

## Use Microsoft Document Connection

Tested with the following apps:

- LibreOffice
- Microsoft Excel
- Microsoft PowerPoint
- Microsoft Word
- NeoOffice.

### Pros

For multiple users of SharePoint, protection through Microsoft Document Connection seems good.

### Cons

No file system integration.

Does not meet the basic requirements of some end users.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the file system integration provided by Apple

Tested with the following apps:

- LibreOffice
- NeoOffice.

### Pros

File system integration is highly desirable.

Open source.

Supported by Apple.

### Cons

Do not expect integration with Excel, PowerPoint or Word:

- [Microsoft SharePoint disallows some characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231)
- [Microsoft Office 2011 requires codes that are deprecated](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51147/8546), proper representations of which are disallowed by SharePoint.

Do not expect all actions in Finder to work:

- Microsoft's disallowance of characters prevents the [integrity that is required by Finder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10561129/38108).

---

I could have tested with other apps. However: since the defaults of SharePoint make file system integration impossible with Microsoft Office – and since it's reasonable to assume that organisations pushing SharePoint will also push Microsoft Office – I decided to focus on other approaches.

#### Understanding the role of Finder

To **initiate** this type of connection to a WebDAV server, there's an interface in Finder (the **Go** menu). However, Finder is not the integrator; Finder is simply an app.

File system integration is around the following bundle, open source for which is provided by Apple:

`/System/Library/Filesystems/webdav.fs`